# 'UserLoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleanned_data' Django

Tags: python, django

Hello i have some trouble with authentification in Django so that's what i have in view.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views import generic
    from FS import forms

    from .forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegisterForm

def login_view(request):
    form= UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    title = "Connexion"
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleanned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleanned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request.user.is_authenticated())

    return render(request,"forms.html",{"form":form, "title": title})



def register_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    title= "Inscription"
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleanned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())
        #redirect

    context = {
    "form":form,
    "title":title
    }
    return render(request,"forms.html", context)

def logout_view(request):
         logout(request)
         return render(request, "forms.html")
```

and that's in forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model

from django.forms import ModelForm

User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password= forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):


        username = self.cleanned_data.get('username')
        passworrd = self.cleanned_data.get('password')


        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exist')
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Mot de passe incorrecte')
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError('plus valide')
        return super(UserLoginForm, forms).clean(*args, **kwargs)




class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

and there is always this error "'UserLoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleanned_data'"

I don't understand, i don't know how to make a form.is_valid() before. I can't see how to change my code to have the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `form.cleaned_data`, not `form.cleanned_data`.

To know more about Django Forms, refer the [documentation..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am not very smart !

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change `form.cleanned_data` to `form.cleaned_data`.